# Why are the Fourier Series an orthogonal basis?

Tags: fourier-series, orthonormal

The Fourier Series of a function $y(x)$ is its expansion into sines and cosines:

$$y(x)= a_0+a_1\cos(x) +b_1\sin(x)+a_2\cos(2x)+b_2\sin(2x)+...$$

An [Orthogonal Basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_basis) for an inner product space $V$ is a basis for $V$ whose vectors are mutually [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality).

For the Fourier Series example above, how do I correctly specify the orthogonal basis $B$ ?

Is it simply $B=\{\cos(x),\sin(x),\cos(2x), \sin(2x),\dots\}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the fourier orthonormal system special? If I chose some arbitary orthonormal system, could I hope for pointwise convergence for nice functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2366438/is-the-fourier-orthonormal-system-special-if-i-chose-some-arbitary-orthonormal)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, together with the constant function.